# Sony camera API simulator

Tags: camera, sony

Is there anyone aware if there is a Sony Camera "simulator" available?
This may greatly ease the development task of SDK based applications.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no emulator or simulator currently available.  You will have to have an actual camera to test with.